# Can I access photo library in background using React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on an app that will need to have background access to user photo library just like how OneDrive uploads user photos to its own cloud in the background.

In this scenario, user doesn't use an image picker but the application itself should access all the photos in the background and process them assuming permissions are given by the user.

I wonder if I need to use native applications for this or if I can use React so it can work for both iOS and Android.

Is this doable with React Native?

Comment: if the images are made by camera before. you can grab them in devicecache

Comment: Do you mean, for the rest of the photos, I cannot access using React Native?

Comment: I can not imagine that you can upload pictures from the device without the user selecting which ones to upload. Imagine the danger to your personal images that would pose. maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: There are plenty of apps do that actually, for example OneDrive as mentioned above. This is not a security hole this is a use case. User would like to use another cloud service to backup their photos instead of using iCloud.